# AWS Step Function - basic authorization error

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have created a simple AWS Step function with a single step (SQS:receive message).
[image]

The process is:

1. I put an message on the SQS queue X (which arrives OK)
2. I start the AWS State machine, expecting it to receive the message

Instead I get the error:

```
    {
    "id": "5",
    "type": "TaskFailed",
    "details": {
        "cause": "The role arn:aws:iam::1234:role/StepFunctionsSandboxRole is not authorized to assume the task state's role, arn:aws:iam::1234:role/StepFunctionsSandboxRole.",
        "error": "States.TaskFailed",
        "resource": "receiveMessage.waitForTaskToken",
        "resourceType": "aws-sdk:sqs"
    },
    "previous_event_id": "4",
    "event_timestamp": "1682488337384",
    "execution_arn": "arn:aws:states:ap-southeast-2:1234:execution:MyStateMachine:78f95d4d-c6aa-b554-3545-07b8f8507b7d"
}
```

**Any suggestions on what is wrong with my IAM setup?**

My step function JSON:

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "ReceiveMessage",
  "States": {
    "ReceiveMessage": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "QueueUrl": "https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/1234/workflow-demo-request"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sqs:receiveMessage.waitForTaskToken",
      "Credentials": {
        "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/StepFunctionsSandboxRole"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 10
}
```

My IAM role's (StepFunctionsSandboxRole) trust relationships:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "states.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to perform cross-account invocation? The `Credentials` field is only used when you want to perform an invocation on a different account, or in the same account but using a different IAM Role.

In your case, looks like both IAM Roles are the same an in this case, you do not need the `Credentials` field in your Task state, as you are already running the execution using the execution role named `StepFunctionsSandboxRole`.

Another thing that I noticed, you have `.waitForTaskToken` in your definition. This is used for [Callback pattern](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/aws-step-functions-support-callback-patterns/) which does not look like you need it. This is for the case where you want to make an invocation (sqs:ReceiveMessage in your case) and something else will report the success. What I understood is that you just want to receive the message, so you don't need the `.waitForTaskToken`.

Comment: So "resource": "receiveMessage.waitForTaskToken" should be "resource": "receiveMessage" ?

Comment: "perform cross-account invocation" - no

Comment: this solved the issue - removing .waitForTaskToken and credentials section in task state